# What is the practice of dropping words from sentences?

Tags: articles

Most instructions for equipment and software make a habit of shortening sentences by dropping words of certain parts of speech - usually definite and indefinite articles.

For example:

> PULL (THE) LEVER TO OPERATE
>
> CARS MAY BE TOWED WHEN (THEY ARE) PARKED ILLEGALLY
>
> PLEASE USE (THE) OTHER DOOR

Is there a name for this custom? And what is the best way to describe it?

Comment: Minimalism, abbreviation, shortening.

Comment: @Yay Thank you for linking that question - exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Abbreviating.

> - [**abbreviate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abbreviate) (əˈbriːvɪˌeɪt)
>     vb (tr)
>
>   1. to shorten (a word or phrase) by contraction or omission of some letters or words

Comment: Can you add a link to your definition?

Comment: Done. Most definitions I found online are pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.

[Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) has its own set of rules, some of which actually do make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

> [elision](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elision) : the act or an instance of omitting something :  omission

Comment: AFAIK elision usually refers to the omission of sounds within words, not to entire words within a sentence.

Comment: @Tom - It can refer to either.

Answer (score 1):

Definite articles are commonly ignored in technical and scientific writing when it's deemed unnecessary and it's clear what is being referred to.

For example, a technical manual would rarely say "pull a lever", it would always say "pull the lever". So "the" is implicit, and "a" must be made explicit, if that's the case.

This is known as [zero-marking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English).